# When to use java.nio.channels.FileChannel compare to java.io.FileWriter?

Tags: java, nio, channel

I saw some `java.nio.channels.FileChannel`'s examples , but i found FileChannel was more complex  to read or write string to file compare to FileWriter . So when to use java.nio.channels.FileChannel ?

Answer (score 0):

FileWriter is text abstraction over output streams from first versions of Java. It does the work reliably, completely and synchronously.

FileChannel is lower level class that offers better performance, random access, but on the other hand you have to convert into bytes array, handle potentially partial writes (although for files this should be safe).

So basically depends on your needs. I would choose FileStreamWriter if I wanted just simple stream.